# Logical Indexing with NA in R - How to set to FALSE or exclude rather than return NA?

Tags: r, logic, missing-data

Apologies if this is a common question, but it has caused some unexpected frustration in a script I am running. I have a dataset which roughly looks like the following (though much larger in practice):

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3, NA, NA, 6), 
                 B = c(10, 20, 30, 40 , 50, 60))
```

My script cycles through a list of values from column A and is supposed to take action based on whether the values in B are larger than 25. However, the corresponding values of B for missing values in A are ALWAYS returned, whereas I want them to always be excluded. For example,

```
df$B[df$A == 6]
```

Gives the output

```
NA NA 60
```

Rather than the expected

```
60
```

Thus, the code

```
df$B[df$A == 6] > 25
```

returns

```
NA NA TRUE
```

rather than just

```
TRUE
```

Could someone explain the reason for this and any simple solutions? The immediate solution that came to mind is to remove any rows with NA values in column A, but I would prefer a solution which is robust to missingness in A and will only return the single desired logical value from B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you ask whether ***N**ot **A**vailable* (`NA`) value  is equal to *number* or *anything else* - you got the only possible answer: *The answer is *Not Available* (`NA`)*.

`NA` *might be* equal to `6`, or to `John the Baptist`, or to ⛄ as well as *to any other object*. It is just impossible to say if it does, since *the value is **n**ot **a**vailable*.

To get the answer you want, you can use `na.omit()` or `na.exclude()` on the results. Or you can apply *yet another logical condition* during subsetting:

```
with(df, B[A == 6 & !is.na(A)])
# [1] 60
```

Comment: Another easy way to do this is to use which(). Which will return the index of the values that match the conditional. Therefore, instead of boolean indexing you could do: df$B[which(df$A == 6)]